# Simple search is not working In Magento 2.1.7

Tags: catalogsearch, magento-2.1.7

I am new to **Magento 2** and facing a problem in simple search. I searched product name but result is not displaying.

The layered navigation return correct answer but product is not showing.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To make your product **visible** on front-end do check below check-list.

1. Check that you have made your **Enable Product** to `yes`.
2. Check that you have entered something in stock details(**Quantity**).
3. Check that you have set product **stock status** to **`Instock`**.
4. Check you set **Visibility** to **`Catalog,Search`**.

After all this perform the below commands form your root directory of Magento

> To fix the indexing problem of the product
>
> ```
> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
> ```
>
> To fix the designing & visibility related problem (due to the cache i.e. site is loading the old view that is without new products).
>
> ```
> php bin/magento cache:flush
> ```

Comment: I have do every thing you told,But i did not show any products in my search result

Comment: What ever it is showing just put the snapshot of it with the question you asked.